# Codeigniter: load view with a query string without modifying core files

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to load a view that uses a string query, like this:

`$this->load->view('mydir/my_view.php?file=myfile.pdf');`

however it appears that CI_Loader checks for the full string if the view is a valid file and it exists, so of course it will never find *mydir/my_view.php?file=myfile.pdf* in the views directory. I really don't want to modify core files and can't figure a way to get around this issue

Comment: read load view with variables: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/loader.html?highlight=load%20view#CI_Loader::vars

Comment: Are you wanting to pass the myfile.pdf into the view? An example of your view would be helpful.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Yes it is necessary that I pass url of the file to my view. It is then processed by a javascript file that I cannot alter. Due to the way it works, I cannot simply pass variables to the view to load the file url, as the only input this JS file accepts are query strings in the url

Comment: So what is in the view that the JS is looking for. There will be a way around this.

Comment: Its looking for the full path to a pdf file. In this case Im using PDFJS Viewer and havent found a way to open the pdf from a url given as a parameter by codeigniter, so Im stuck passing it as a query string, which it supports by default.

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do following:

```
$data = ['file'=>'myfile.pdf'];
$this->load->view('mydir/my_view',$data);
```

in your view you can access `$file`

[reference](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/loader.html?highlight=load%20view#CI_Loader::view)